# add logo on picture taken in our app like B612 camera app

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i am developing an app in which you can take picture with wearing glasses like snapchat filters. Now i need to place a logo somewhere on that picture that is taken by our app like when you take image from B612 camera app there logo will appear at the bottom of picture. I have no idea how to do that. If someone can help I shall be very thankful.

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/95574/how-to-add-a-logo-to-a-captured-image

Comment: it doesnot work

Comment: @derHugo can you help